# How can I access wordpress database(like category or post id) in a form made in text widget for sidebars?

Tags: wordpress

I made a form and placed in text widget for sidebar.How can I access the category of the post to be used in this particular form?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`get_the_category`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category) function to return the category from the current post. Here is an example of how to use this functions **outside** the loop

```
<?php
global $post;
$categories = get_the_category($post->ID);
var_dump($categories);
?>
```

**EDIT**

By default you cannot use PHP in a text widget. To make this work, download and install [PHP Text Widget](https://wordpress.org/plugins/php-text-widget/). You can use the php code in your text widget

Comment: Can I use the php code inside text widget.If not,then where do I place           the code to get the category and use in that form?

Comment: Check my edit and check out the examples in the link I've given you